# how we append different word on same palce in 2D list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In code,I make 3 variable that take max in each row of 2D list.I want to put or replace True in that place where max variable present.`

```
m=[[8, 7, 9], [6, 7, 6], [3, 2, 5]]
a=max(m[0])
b=max(m[1])
c=max(m[2])
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if(m[i][j]==a):
            m.append(True)
        else:
            print(m[i][j])
8
7
6
7
6
3
2
5




        `
```

Comment: expected output? problem description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the `.append()` function, which will just tag it on the end of the list. You need to set the number that equals `a` to `True`. To replace the item, just set it equal to `True`. To do this, just replace:

```
m.append(True)
```

with:

```
m[i][j] = True
```

This will print:
`[[8, 7, True], [6, 7, 6], [3, 2, 5]]`

In your example:

```
m=[[8, 7, 9], [6, 7, 6], [3, 2, 5]]
a=max(m[0])
b=max(m[1])
c=max(m[2])
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if(m[i][j]==a):
            m[i][j] = True  # this line
        else:
            print(m[i][j])
```

**EDIT:**

Full output, for clarification:

```
8
7
6
7
6
3
2
5
[[8, 7, True], [6, 7, 6], [3, 2, 5]]
```

Comment: but not come that output.you mentioned above.I run you code??

Comment: Can you edit your post with the ouput you got when you ran my code?

Comment: last line of output you print separately

Comment: actually i check on given output not print list separate.thanks my problem solved

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: Another problem raise when i condition apply for b then true come 2 times in m [0] how do i handle?